# Compare dates using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, time

I am trying to parse sheet with time stamps and count number of occurrences.
my data have header (date, hour, instance, day), so I want to parse through days and when there is new day I record time (this is time of first event that day) and increment counter  next to that "time" value (I add list of timestamps at column 11)
My code is:

```
Sub Count()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim Day As String
Dim Vrijeme As Date
Dim test As Date


For i = 1 To 5673


If Cells(i, 4).Value <> Day Then   
        Day = Cells(i, 4).Value
        Vrijeme = Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
        
        For j = 5 To 500
        test = Cells(j, 11).Value
        
        
           If Vrijeme = test Then     // This is place that doesn t work 
                counter = Cells(j, 12).Value
                counter = counter + 1
                Cells(j, 12).Value = counter
                
            End If
            DoEvents
            
            
         Next j
        
    End If
    

Next i

End Sub
```

But this doesn t work, I event manualy set cell format to "Time" ... any idea why this doesn t work. when I do debug variable read data correctly but when it compare values this don t work ...

thx

Answer (score 0):

try to use TimebValue and DateValue.
as

```
Day = DateValue(Cells(i, 4))
Vrijeme = TimeValue(Cells(i + 1, 2))
test = TimebValue (Cells(j, 11))
```

You need to compare comparable values, to be 100% sure that they are comparable convert them bout in one format.

Comment: Runtime error 13, Type mismatch , I converted time to minutes from midnight and worked fine.... I am quite sure that problem is related to cell format